# Yeoman won´t scaffold backbone app

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm using yeoman to scaffold a backbone app with the generator-backbone, however, everytime I run `yo backbone`, it ends up with this messages:

```
I'm all done. Running bower install for you to install the required dependencies. If this fails, try running the command yourself.

I'm all done. Running bower install & npm install for you to install the required dependencies. If this fails, try running the command yourself.

npm WARN package.json webdev@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json webdev@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json webdev@0.0.0 No README data
```

And then, my directory is empty. There is no scaffold whatsoever.

The steps I took were this:

1. Create a directory: `mkdir test`
2. cd into test: `cd test`
3. run the generator: `yo backbone`

I don´t know what else to do, my directory always appears empty!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to follow the same steps as you described but not able to reproduce the issue.

But you can try reinstalling generator-backbone.

`npm cache clean`
`npm install -g generator-backbone@0.2.2`

Please lemme know if you face the same issue after these steps.

Comment: I tried it with the following version, and it works: `npm install -g generator-backbone@0.2.8`